# Make End key move to line wrap when using lineWrapping in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

In browser textarea editors (as well as in other editors, Sublime, Notepad++, etc), pressing the <kbd>End</kbd> key would move the caret to the end of the current line where it is wrapped. In case the caret is already there, it will instead be taken to the end of the paragraph.

However, when using:

```
lineWrapping: true
```

in CodeMirror, the <kbd>End</kbd> key will take the caret directly to the end of the paragraph instead of the end of the current line.

Is there any easy way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `CodeMirror.keymap.default.End = "goLineRight"`, which will do the first thing you describe (move to the right of the wrapped part of the line), but that does not currently go all the way to the end of the line if you press it twice.

(Similarly, `CodeMirror.keymap.default.Home = "goLineLeft"` for the Home key.)

Comment: Works perfectly! Also, the first step is the most important as PageDown/PageUp does the "paragraph" thing in my usecase. I added it in `extraKeys: { "End": "goLineRight", "Home": "goLineLeft"}`, but it is just the same. Thanks for a great library, Marijn!